# указатель на 8байтный (64-битный) значение может указывать на ячейку памяти не кратное 8?

Tags: c++, c, выравнивание

можно ли писать такой код:

```
uint8_t a[SOME_COUNT];
int main()
{
    uint64_t *t = (uint64_t *)a;    // c-style я знаю
    /* some code*/
}
```

указатель на 8байтный (64-битный) значение может указывать на ячейку памяти не кратное 8?

Comment: 64-битный указатель, или указатель на 64-битное значение?

Comment: Проблемы с выравниванием бывают в структурах. Массивы по определению лежат всегда подряд. Но если пишется такой код (низкоуровневый с доступом к байтам), то лучше просто выключать выравнивание.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

указывать может, но формально это undefined behavior.
по стандарту, несвязанные типы указателей можно кастовать только к char*.

логически объясняется тем, что это мешает оптимизиациям и на некоторых платформах могут возникать проблемы при доступе к невыровненным данным.

но т.к. подобного кода написано достаточно много, то например в gcc есть параметр -fno-strict-aliasing

Comment: можно ссылку на стандарт и номер пункта?

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf
пункт 6.5 7

Comment: 6.5.7.3 на сколько я понял там говорится про операции смещение. И что если сместить на отрицательную величину или на величину большее чем ширина числа, то поведение не определено.
Так что я не увидел где стоит запрет или неопределенность преобразований

Comment: An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
the following types:88)
— a type compatible with the effective type of the object.
эту ошибку легко воспроизвести, особенно со всякими -O3

Comment: видимо туго всасываю. Все равно не осознал что тут написано

Comment: https://habr.com/post/114117/